# Get the pull request ID of a continuous deployment release [Azure Pipelines]

Tags: azure, triggers, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am trying to setup azure pipelines to trigger a build on every PR update, and a release on every merge. For a couple of reasons when the PR is merged, i need to access data saved by the latest validation build of the PR.

However to do that i need the PRid during the run of the Release pipeline. How can one achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your scenario, to my knowledge, it is complex to get related build information in your release. Besides, it may cause unexpected result if not cover all possible scenarios.

I'd suggest that you could refer to these steps blow:

1. Remove publish build/pipeline artifact or unnecessary tasks, just remain tasks for validation, **which will save a lot of time**. (Because, in general, the validation build will be triggered too many times, waste too much time to publish useless artifact or other data)
2. Create a new build pipeline and enable Continuous integration for target branch (e.g. master)
3. Add publish build/pipeline artifact task
4. Edit release pipeline and link this build pipeline and enable Continuous deployment. (Could add additional filters)

With this way, after completing the pull request, this new build pipeline will be triggered and will publish necessary artifact, then the release will be triggered.

For pull request validation builds, they just do tasks to validate the code (e.g. build project), but not publish artifact.

Simple scenario for saving time:

A pull request has 50 validation builds

- old way: publish artifact of each takes 1 minutes, then total time is 50 minutes
- new way: the new pipeline do tasks for build and publish, it just run once and may just takes 10 minutes.

Then you can save 40 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem. As we use a cloud platform, every test build returns us an id that we can use to deploy immediately the tested packages. Using your method we cant get PR data during the merge and use the latest passing id, but we have to deploy again with a new build. I managed to do this using the REST api and getting the latest build of the latest merged PR. Since i realize my request is niche, i will mark your answer as correct since you provided a very detailed reponse. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

From the release you can retrieve the commit Id which triggered the build.
Then you search for the commitId in the list of completed PRs and retrieve your PR number.

```
$commitId = "$(RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.{YOURARTIFACTALIAS}.SOURCEVERSION)"
$repoId = "$(RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.{YOURARTIFACTALIAS}.REPOSITORY.ID)"

$pullRequestsUri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}_apis/git/repositories/" + $repoId + "/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=completed&api-version=5.1"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", "$(System.AccessToken)")))

$pullRequests = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pullRequestsUri -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" }

foreach ($value in $pullRequests.value) {
    if ($value.lastMergeCommit.commitId -eq $commitId) {
        $pullRequestId = $value.pullRequestId
    }
}

Write-Host $pullRequestId
```

Answer (score 1):

In Release Pipeline, you could use the variable `$(RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.<<Source alias name>>.PULLREQUEST.ID)` to get the Pull Request ID.

[image: Release Variables]

Note: the Source alias name is the name set in the release artifacts.

[image: Source alias]

By the way, if you use a default variable in your script, you must first replace the `.` in the default variable names with `_`.

For example: `$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_<<Source alias name>>_PULLREQUEST_ID`

Here is a doc about [the Release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#using-default-variables).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok first of all thank you. If i understand correctly, i make 2 pipelines, one build, and one release. The build pipeline publishes an artifact and runs on every PR validation. The release pipeline though has to be continous on the master branch of the repo, since i want to deploy during a merge. But during the release there does not seem to be any information about a pull request

Comment: @dac1n  You need to create connection between release and pull request.You set the CD (Continuous deployment  trigger) to be triggered by build on master branch. This means that  the release will only be triggered when the build is on master. In this case, it will not contain pull request information. So when the build runs on PR validation. It will not trigger the release(CD is invalid). If you want to get the Pull RequestID via the variable , you could set the CD to be triggered by build on PR branch.The expression:`Include = refs/pull/*` . Or  you could use Pull Request Trigger.

Comment: Ok but if use that then the trigger will run on every validation and not when the PR completes. My ultimate goal is this. 1. Validate each PR, which generates an artifact every time (just a json file which i need) the validation runs. 2. When the PR is merged, use the last validation artifact for a script. If i use a pull request trigger then it doesn't run when merged. If i use a normal branch trigger then i lose the PR info

Comment: @dac1n According to your requirements , maybe you could try to add two filters to Continuous deployment trigger. 1.`Include = refs/pull/*` , this could make sure that the Pull Request build could trigger the release pipeline. 2. `Include = master`, this could make sure that the release pipeline will run after the PR is merged.