# Get pull request Id from azure devop classic deployment pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I checked several sources, seems possible, but can't get it work.

What I want is that whenever a PR is created and PR build is successful, then a PR release is run and a site is created (either with PR Id or PR source branch, e.g. pr122--xxx.azuresite.net).

From an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820405/get-the-pull-request-id-of-a-continuous-deployment-release-azure-pipelines),
Looks like I could use release.artifacts.alias.PULLREQUEST.ID, but when I tried it, this doesn't work at all. Also from the official doc, there is no mention of this variable. Is this only for the new YAML pipeline?

As most of our things are in classic pipeline, the solution I can think of is to parse the build source, which is refs/pull/11201/merge. Looks like 11201 is the Pull Request ID, so I just need to replace refs, pull,merge and "/". But I am not sure if better approaches available.

Comment: Hi daxu, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Following this doc: [Deploy pull request Artifacts with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops), we can successfully create a pull request deployment by choosing Azure Repos as the source artifact.
[image]
[image]
If one pull request is created, a new release will be triggered. And as you have found, the source branch of build source is `"refs/pull/{PullRequestId}/merge"`, so you are right.

In addition, if you set the Azure Repos as the [primary artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#art-primary), we can get the pull request branch by using the predefined variable `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceBranch`. In below example, we can use the [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to run below command.

`Write-Host "Release.Artifacts._215.SourceBranch: $(Release.Artifacts._215.SourceBranch)`

See: [Default variables - General Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---general-artifact) for details.